# email handling with inbox.py and nginx

Tags: email, nginx, python

I have a Flask web application running behind gunicorn and Nginx.  Nginx proxies any traffic to ivrhub.org to the correct flask app.

I would very much like to use [inbox.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/inbox.py) to process some incoming email.  Running inbox.py's example on my server and then sending an email to hello@ivrhub.org does not work as I intended.  The inbox.py server does not seem to receive anything but the email also does not bounce.

I'm missing something conceptually -- is there a DNS setting I need to configure or something I need to adjust with Nginx?